# How do I Monitor Mouse Movement Events in All Windows (Not Just One) on X11

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, x11

I'm trying write an X11 program to monitor all mouse movements on the desktop. The program should be able to receive a notification whenever the mouse is moved by the human user, or moved programmatically via `XWarpPointer()` by a robotic application. I know it should be possible by setting a `PointerMotionMask` via `XSelectInput()` and monitor `MotionNotify`, but I'm having troubles receiving mouse events from *all* windows, not just one.

Initially, I just tried to receive pointer motion events from the root window, in the following demo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *display;
    Window root_window;
    XEvent event;

    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0); 
    XSelectInput(display, root_window, PointerMotionMask);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        switch(event.type) { 
            case MotionNotify:
                printf("x: %d y: %d\n", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y );
                break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't receive any events, unless the mouse pointer is on an empty desktop background. It's clear that merely receiving events from the root window won't work. Then I tried a workaround: first, set `SubstructureNotifyMask` on the root window to monitor all `CreateNotify` events to catch all newly created windows, then call `XSelectInput()` to enable the `PointerMotionMask` on these windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *display;
    Window root_window;
    XEvent event;

    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0); 
    XSelectInput(display, root_window, SubstructureNotifyMask);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        switch(event.type) { 
            case CreateNotify:
                XSelectInput(display, event.xcreatewindow.window, PointerMotionMask);
                break;
            case MotionNotify:
                printf("x: %d y: %d\n", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y);
                break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This approach is more successful, I started to receive some mouse events from new windows. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work in all portions inside a window - for example, it cannot receive mouse events from the console area in terminal emulators, but can receive events when the mouse is located around the title bar. It appears that a window can create more subwindows, so the mouse events won't be recorded.

Then I tried another workaround - set both `SubstructureNotifyMask` and `PointerMotionMask` in `CreateNotify`, so when a window creates a child window, `SubstructureNotifyMask` ensures more `CreateNotify` events will be received in a recursive manner, so all child windows will get `PointerMotionMask` as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *display;
    Window root_window;
    XEvent event;

    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0); 
    XSelectInput(display, root_window, SubstructureNotifyMask);

    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        switch(event.type) { 
            case CreateNotify:
                XSelectInput(display, event.xcreatewindow.window, SubstructureNotifyMask | PointerMotionMask);
                break;
            case MotionNotify:
                printf("x: %d y: %d\n", event.xmotion.x, event.xmotion.y);
                break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

It works a bit better than the second example, but it's not reliable:

- X is fully asynchronous, is it possible that the child window got created before we had a chance to `XSelectInput()`?
- Sometimes it just reports a `BadWindow` error and crashes.
- X event handling becomes messy - if the program already handles a lot of different X events, enabling `SubstructureNotifyMask` recursively will make many unrelated events delivered to other handlers, and it's a pain to add extra code to discriminate between wanted and unwanted events.

---

So, how do I monitor mouse movement events in all windows on X11?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some research, especially reading the source code of Xeyes (I always fell the demo is stupid, but it helps a lot here!), I found:

- Calling `XSelectInput()` on all the windows and subwindows is a futile attempt, you have to set a mask on every single window and child window ever created, it's not a robust solution, and not recommended.
- Instead, it's better to just continuously pulling the mouse pointer from the X server explicitly via `XQueryPointer()`, rather than asking the X server to push MotionEvent to us.

One naive solution is simply setting up a timer by `XtAppAddTimeOut()` and calling `XQueryPointer()` periodically, it works, and indeed, [it was what Xeyes did in the past](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xeyes/-/commit/420c2d8517246c9e422739cadb7acb29e35a3bed#1ccfd61059933f49ae5dd55cbc3ee209d6caa608_632_726)! But it unnecessarily wastes CPU time. Nowadays, the best practice is to take advantage of XInputExtention 2.0. The workflow is:

1. Initialize XInput v2.0
2. Enable various masks via `XISetMask()` and `XIEventMask()` to receive `XI_RawMotion` events (or `XI_Motion`, see notes below) from `XIAllMasterDevices` (or `XIAllDevices`).
3. When a `XI_RawMotion` (or `XI_Motion`) event has been received, call `XQueryPointer()`.
4. `XQueryPointer()` returns:

   - Mouse coordinates with respect to the root window.
   - The active window under the mouse cursor, if any.
5. Perform a `XTranslateCoordinates()` if we want relative coordinates with respect to the active window under the mouse cursor.

### Demo

Here's a demo (save as `mouse.c`, compile with `gcc mouse.c -o mouse -lX11 -lXi`). However, it cannot detect `XWarpPointer()`, see notes below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XInput2.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Display *display;
    Window root_window;

    /* Initialize (FIXME: no error checking). */
    display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    root_window = XRootWindow(display, 0);

    /* check XInput */
    int xi_opcode, event, error;
    if (!XQueryExtension(display, "XInputExtension", &xi_opcode, &event, &error)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: XInput extension is not supported!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Check XInput 2.0 */
    int major = 2;
    int minor = 0;
    int retval = XIQueryVersion(display, &major, &minor);
    if (retval != Success) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: XInput 2.0 is not supported (ancient X11?)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /*
     * Set mask to receive XI_RawMotion events. Because it's raw,
     * XWarpPointer() events are not included, you can use XI_Motion
     * instead.
     */
    unsigned char mask_bytes[(XI_LASTEVENT + 7) / 8] = {0};  /* must be zeroed! */
    XISetMask(mask_bytes, XI_RawMotion);

    /* Set mask to receive events from all master devices */
    XIEventMask evmasks[1];
    /* You can use XIAllDevices for XWarpPointer() */
    evmasks[0].deviceid = XIAllMasterDevices;
    evmasks[0].mask_len = sizeof(mask_bytes);
    evmasks[0].mask = mask_bytes;
    XISelectEvents(display, root_window, evmasks, 1);

    XEvent xevent;
    while (1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &xevent);

        if (xevent.xcookie.type != GenericEvent || xevent.xcookie.extension != xi_opcode) {
            /* not an XInput event */
            continue;
        }
        XGetEventData(display, &xevent.xcookie);
        if (xevent.xcookie.evtype != XI_RawMotion) {
            /*
             * Not an XI_RawMotion event (you may want to detect
             * XI_Motion as well, see comments above).
             */
            XFreeEventData(display, &xevent.xcookie);
            continue;
        }
        XFreeEventData(display, &xevent.xcookie);

        Window root_return, child_return;
        int root_x_return, root_y_return;
        int win_x_return, win_y_return;
        unsigned int mask_return;
        /*
         * We need:
         *     child_return - the active window under the cursor
         *     win_{x,y}_return - pointer coordinate with respect to root window
         */
        int retval = XQueryPointer(display, root_window, &root_return, &child_return,
                                   &root_x_return, &root_y_return,
                                   &win_x_return, &win_y_return,
                                   &mask_return);
        if (!retval) {
            /* pointer is not in the same screen, ignore */
            continue;
        }

        /* We used root window as its reference, so both should be the same */
        assert(root_x_return == win_x_return);
        assert(root_y_return == win_y_return);

        printf("root: x %d y %d\n", root_x_return, root_y_return);

        if (child_return) {
            int local_x, local_y;
            XTranslateCoordinates(display, root_window, child_return,
                                  root_x_return, root_y_return,
                                  &local_x, &local_y, &child_return);
            printf("local: x %d y %d\n\n", local_x, local_y);
        }
    }

    XCloseDisplay(display);

    return 0;
}
```

### Sample Output

```
root: x 631 y 334
local: x 140 y 251

root: x 628 y 338
local: x 137 y 255

root: x 619 y 343
local: x 128 y 260
```

### `XWarpPointer()` Troubles

The demo above doesn't work if the pointer is moved via `XWarpPointer()` by a robotic application on newer systems after X.Org 1.10.4. This is intentional, see [Bug 30068](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30068) on FreeDesktop.

In order to receive mouse events triggered by all mouse movements, including `XWarpPointer()`, change `XI_RawMotion` to `XI_Motion`, and change `XIAllMasterDevices` to `XIAllDevices`.

### References

This demo lacks error checking and may contain bugs. If in doubts, please check the following authoritative references.

- [Tracking Cursor Position](https://keithp.com/blogs/Cursor_tracking/) by [Keith Packard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Packard), a real X expert, has been heavily involved in the development of X since the late 1980s, and responsible for many X extensions and technical papers.
- [Xeyes source code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xeyes/-/blob/master/Eyes.c) from X.Org.

Comment: Excellent answer and good job for having the persistence to answer this question for yourself and share the answer with others.

Comment: When I try to compile this, I get the error "X11/extensions/XInput2.h: No such file or directory". I am on ubuntu - where can I find the XInput2 headers?

Comment: @AlexSpurling `apt install libxi-dev`